# problem in setting height of iframe in web page

Tags: html, css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

[image]i have a simple webpage made by using bootstrap.now i want to embed it in another webpage but i have a problem in setting the height .
here is my webpage:

```
 <html> 
        <head>
        <style>
            #above1 { margin-bottom:6px; }
            #iframe1 { height:100%; width:100%; border: 1px solid #0094ff; border-radius:3px; padding-top:6px;  }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div id="above1">        
                    <div class="row"> [content here]</div>
                    <div class="row"> [more content here]</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <iframe id="iframe1" src="home.html"></iframe>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

here is my  home.html webpage which i want to embed is:

```
`<htlm>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <img src="image/2.png" >
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">

                            <img src="image/1.png" >
                        </div>


            </div>
                    </div>
    </body>
    </html>`
```

when i implement this  i got scrollbar in iframe how i gonna fix this issue?

Comment: did you try setting height:100% in your homepage? for wrapping element for iframe?

Comment: you wnat the iframe to take the whole height and width of the screen?

Comment: yes @AKASHPANDEY but in webpage i have another elements so height should be takes according to it. i want to remove inner scrollbar

Comment: try using height: fit-content and is there any way i can see it live ??

Comment: Create a code snippet or codepen of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height` and `width` in #iframe1

This Script to help you to auto-adjust the `width` and `height` of the iframe to fit with content in it.

```
<script type="application/javascript">

function resizeIFrameToFitContent( iFrame ) {

    iFrame.width  = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    iFrame.height = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {

    var iFrame = document.getElementById( 'iframe1' );
    resizeIFrameToFitContent( iFrame );

    // or, to resize all iframes:
    var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
    for( var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
        resizeIFrameToFitContent( iframes[i] );
    }
} );

</script>

<iframe id="iframe1" src="home.html"></iframe>
```